# How to upgrade Self-hosted action runner?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners, github-actions-runners

Self-hosted GitHub actions runner installed on Linux, Windows and Mac systems.

I need to upgrade the runner version to latest on Linux, Windows and MacOS.

1. How to check the currently installed Runner version?

In runner `log` and `service status` side, I can't find the information.

2. How to upgrade the runner to latest version?

Please help me with information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the self hosted runner directory, list folders, you should see the bin and externals directory with the version suffix bin.**2.288.1**, externals.**2.288.1** - most current should have symlink with full directory. Also you can check version of each component listener, plugin-host,worker in /bin directory json files. There's no need to force updating self hosted runner - it should update automatically to the latest. One scenario in which you will need to update the runners manually is inside docker container - you can use this script:

https://github.com/GarnerCorp/github-actions-runner/blob/cb604618a600bd5174f3dbc8d51d15eee6585c68/scripts/install-runner